# AWS Apprunner with route53 mapping

Tags: amazon-route53, amazon-app-runner

I was trying to deploy docker service using aws app-runner. Deploying a service and running it is very street forward. Once I deployed the app, aws gives me url to access my service. Now I want to route traffic from my domain to this url. In route 53 it doesn't seems this option is not available, I might be wrong. In aws app-runner it self there is an option to link the url generated by aws with my domain name. I follow that option but it seems I have to do dns configuration change and CNAM configuration. Is there anyone who have tried this option and able to guid me? Thanks!

Comment: Did you solved your problem? I have the same issue...